# Fetching API and return Specific data

Tags: javascript, json, api

So, I am trying to fetch `API` from [Calendarific](https://calendarific.com/api-documentation) I fetch it and I get data in `console` here is the code below:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function fetchApi(){
fetch('https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=<myKey>&country=US&year=2019')
.then(res => res.text())
.then(data => {
    //holiday.innerHTML = data;
    //console.log(data);
    console.log(data.holidays[0].name)
})
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
  // alert('click')
});
```

But I want to access specific data like. I want to access only the `name` and how can I do that? `Code` works fine but I faced problem to access specific data from `API` I tried `holidays[0].name` But it shows `undefined` What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: res -> res.json()

Comment: show us how the data looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When receiving JSON, instead of

```
.then(res => res.text())
.then(...
```

use

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(...
```

Also, according to [calendarific documentation](https://calendarific.com/api-documentation), there's a `response` key you should query first:

```
console.log(data.response.holidays[0].name)
```

Comment: Okay! Thank You I got it I thought for displaying `data` on the browser I need to use `res.text()` but now I am confused about in which condition I need to use `res.text()`?

Comment: When the URL you are querying return a text, use text, when it's a json, use json

Comment: You can post a new question